# Customer login is not working in Magento

Tags: magento

I have to upgrade Magento version 1.7 to 1.9. Its login is not working and there is no error in console or screen. Login popup at checkout page and social logins are working properly.

Comment: check this may help to you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31933/customer-login-doesnt-work-in-1-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below lines in Login template in your current theme:

Template Path: `template\persistent\customer\form\login.phtml`

Add this `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>` After Form Tag open